# Diminuir sintaxe de if else

Tags: java, eclipse

tenho o seguinte código, e gostaria de reduzir ele utilizando outra sintaxe ou até mesmo outro método.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double data;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("\nDigite um ano e encontre o seculo que ele pertence ");
    data = sc.nextDouble();

    if (data >= 1 && data <= 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 1");
    } 
    else if (data >= 101 && data <= 200 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 2");
    }
    else if (data >= 201 && data <= 300 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 3");
    }
    else if (data >= 301 && data <= 400 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 4");
    }
    else if (data >= 401 && data <= 500 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 5");
    }
    else if (data >= 501 && data <= 600 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 6");
    }
    else if (data >= 501 && data <= 600 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 6");
    }
    else if (data >= 601 && data <= 700 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 7");
    }
    else if (data >= 701 && data <= 800 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 8");
    }
    else if (data >= 801 && data <= 900 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 9");
    }
    else if (data >= 901 && data <= 1000 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 10");
    }
    else if (data >= 1001 && data <= 1100)
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 11");
    }
    else if (data >= 1101 && data <= 1200 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 12");
    }
    else if (data >= 1201 && data <= 1300 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 13");
    }
    else if (data >= 1301 && data <= 1400 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 14");
    }
    else if (data >= 1401 && data <= 1500 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 15");
    }
    else if (data >= 1501 && data <= 1600 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 16");
    }
    else if (data >= 1601 && data <= 1700 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 17");
    }
    else if (data >= 1701 && data <= 1800 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 18");
    }
    else if (data >= 1801 && data <= 1900 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 19");
    }
    else if (data >= 1901 && data <= 2000 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 20");
    }
    else if (data >= 2001 && data <= 2100 )
    {
        System.out.println("Essa data pertence ao Seculo 21");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Data Invalida");
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Acredito que seu problema não seja reduzir os ifs/elses, e sim, uma forma mais objetiva de como detectar um século. Creio que isso ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661275/5524514

Comment: @BlastoiseOpressor muito obrigado!

Comment: Seu problema não está nos if elses, de uma olhada na api do java 8 sobre data, vai lher ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

Olha, em questão à sua pergunta em si, existe 3 maneiras básicas de comparar valores nas linguagens de programações de alto nível, que são: if/else, switch, operador ternário.

Uso do if/else:

```
if(condição){ //executada se verdadeira
   //something
}
else{ //executada caso ao contrário
  //something
}
```

uso do switch:

```
//Verificação de nomes
switch(variavel){
  case "Ana": // executa o trecho de código caso variavel seja = "Ana"
       System.out.Println("Olá, ana!");
       /* Note que o break é necessário na 
        maioria das linguagens para que todos
        os trechos a seguir não sejam executados */
       break;
  case "Roberto":
       System.out.Println("Olá, Roberto!");
       break;
 default:
    //Execute algo que não se encaixa nas anteriores
    System.out.println("Olá, desconhecido!");
    break;
}
```

Uso do operador ternário:

```
numero1 < numero2 ? System.out.println("Número 1 menor") : System.out.println("Número 1 maior ou igual");
```

Depois da explicação de cada tipo de estrutura de comparação eu posso te alertar que esse não é o melhor jeito de achar em qual século estamos. Desse jeito que você fez é algo super manual, e nós programadores precisamos automatizar tudo que vemos.

Sabendo que um século possui 100 anos nós podemos usar um pouco de matemática, então essa maneira pode te ajudar:

```
//Apenas print isso na tela do terminal, aquela cadeia de if/else é desnecessária com a ajuda da matemática
   if(AnoAtual % 100 == 0){
     SeculoAtual = AnoAtual / 100) 
  }
 else{
    SeculoAtual = (AnoAtual / 100) + 1
 }
```

Comment: Sua conta só leva em consideração que o cálculo do século somente será correto apenas quando o ano não for divisível por 100(ou seja, a divisão tem resto). Quando o ano for divisível por 100, não há a necessidade de se adicionar mais um, pois [a definição de século](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9culo) diz que *"começa no início de um ano "01" e termina no ano "00" posterior mais próximo"*

Comment: Verdade, estão certo vocês dois, era de madrugada e eu estava meio com sono, então deixei passar. O post já foi alterado.